# Opção deletar, editar, copiar

Tags: phpmyadmin

Quero deletar um item na table do phpmyadmin mas não aparece, Como faço para aparecer estas opções? vou deixar um print abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Que versão do phpMyAdmin está usando? poste um full print do phpmyadmin tbm, não só uma parte. Tente também outro navegador para ver o resultado.

Comment: A Versão é 4.1.8 mais em outras tables aparece sem problemas.

Comment: aparece essa mensagem Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.

Comment: Pelo que estou vendo no print, todos produtos tem ID = 1 então o phpmyadmin não pode selecionar uma row, já que ele não teria o que selecionar. tente clicar na aba SQL e fazer um `SELECT item,howmany,price FROM \`tabela\` WHERE item="banana"` e o phpmyadmin deve "funcionar" mas esse problema ta na sua tabela, faz um **ALTER** para deixar o campo ID como PQ (Primary Key) na aba estrutura

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128025/como-setar-uma-primary-key-a-uma-tabela-j%C3%A1-existente-no-oracle

Answer (score 2):

Provavelmente a conta de utilizador que está a usar para aceder à base de dados não tem permissões para editar, criar ou apagar.

No cPanel, vá a "Base de Dados MySQL" e associe uma nova conta à base de dados mas desta vez atribua todos os privilégios à relação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

O PhpMyAdmin está te informando que não existe chave primária nessa tabela. Ele não tem como identificar quais campos utilizar para fazer UPDATE, DELETE, etc.
Tente definir a chave primária da tabela e veja se consegue.

Answer (score 1):

O mysql precisa de uma chave primaria, mas correntemente falando, experimente adicionar um campo id na tabela e marcar o AI(Auto incremento) assim ele vai preencher o campos com ids e vai habilitar os campos para edição( fazer updates, inserts... etc)