# Como setar uma primary key a uma tabela já existente no Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Geralmente faço diretamente pela IDE (Sql Developer), mas preciso rodar o script dessa vez.

Supondo a tabela existente `TB_CR_INDICADOR_PERIODO` e a coluna `COD_CR_INDICADOR_PERIODO` como a coluna de identificação única, como eu poderia setar essa *primary key*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O comando correto para adicionar a primary key seria:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name PRIMARY KEY (column1, column2, ... column_n);
```

Aplicando ao seu caso ficaria:

```
ALTER TABLE TB_CR_INDICADOR_PERIODO ADD CONSTRAINT pk_tb_cr_indicador_periodo PRIMARY KEY (COD_CR_INDICADOR_PERIODO);
```

Pode ocorrer erro caso a tabela já possua alguma informação.

Fonte:
http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/primary_keys.php

Comment: select COD_CR_INDICADOR_PERIODO from TB_CR_INDICADOR_PERIODO group by COD_CR_INDICADOR_PERIODOhaving count(*) > 1    vai mostrar se existe alguma duplicata nesta chave.